# Add Filter to not show items in SPS2013 Lists, which have the closing date

Tags: list-view

How do I only show items where date field value is in the future?

Answer (score 0):

```
Closing date is greater than or equal to [Today]
```

Works if you wanna show the ones that are being closed today and in the future.

Otherwise change `is greater than or equal` to to `greater than` to show items that will be closed the next day and further on.

**Update**

To show only items after a publishing date and stop them when the expiry date is equal to today, set up your filter like this:

`Publish date is less than or equal to [Today] AND Closing date is greater than or equal to [Today]`.

Comment: I want to show only those items that have not rached the closing date.

Comment: Then set up the filter: Closing date is greater than [Today]

Comment: Also show items once it reaches the publishing  date n dissappear wen it reaches the closing date. So publish n closing filter within a list.

Comment: tried with publish date is equal to [Today], but then the item disapper once the publish date is not the current date. Any suggestions.

Comment: See my updated answer.